# vim: display the type of C aggregate (struct/union) members, even when nested

Tags: c, vim, types, ctags

I often find myself reading other developer's C code containing expressions like

```
 ptr->member1.member2[i].another_member.final_member = 42;
```

and needing to find out what type `final_member` is. Usually what I do is to track down the chain of types using C tags, starting at the declaration of `ptr` and digging my way into the chain of members. This is cumbersome and often I'm stuck somewhere scratching my head, asking myself "What was the next member in the chain?" To make matters worse, a simple grep for `final_member` in the source tree turns up too many false positives due to the name being reused in more than one struct.

Is there a way to make vim give me the answer directly? I'm willing to install any plugin and even type a few characters while the cursor is on the `final_member` or select the whole expression :-) Non-GUI solutions preferred.

Comment: this is c++ `->` right

Comment: @aaronman Nope, C, ever since K&R :-)

Comment: Huh I though C didn't have the `->` operator, guess it does

Comment: @aaronman Maybe you're thinking of `->*`? That would be C++ only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really suggest you to use plugin clang_complete (or some other plugin powered by clang) for completion. It will give you *pure* completion of C/C++/Objective-C code by real compiler, not ugly method by tags. Each item in completion menu also has type of field (that's what you are looking for)

Omnicppcomplete fails often on complicated expressions. Clang works great, since it is real awesome compiler.

Comment: Okay, I've installed it. The possible completions after a `->` or `.` do display the type. But can this be made to display the type even without actually completing, i.e. when the membername is already complete, say, by calling a function?

Comment: You should then put cursor at the end of the function name, and press Ctrl+X Ctrl+U. This actually will show completion menu with single menuitem.

Comment: Alright, I made a mapping for command mode: `map T hei<C-X><C-U>` which does the trick. But this puts me in insert mode (if I append `<Esc>` the popup vanishes after one second). Is there a way to show the completion from within command mode and make it vanish with the next key press event?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

If i'm working on a project with several nested structs i add `preview` to the `completeopt` option.

In combination with the excellent `omnicppcomplete` plugin a tiny scratch window pops up if you select an entry in the completion menu. That scratch window shows some properties of the selected tag. Among other things it contains the search pattern for the tag which in case of a struct member usually contains its datatype.